# Скорее всего проблема с импортом пакетов

Tags: java, swing

Есть класс Tetris в нем находится полностью рабочая игра, если запускаю игру в через этот класс, то все прекрасно работает, есть класс ClientLauncher, он находится в другом пакете, когда пытаюсь запустить игру через второй класс вот что выходит: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но секунд через 40 игра всё же появляется но уже я успел проиграть.
Если игра долго грузится, то где мб проблема?

Вот код ClientLauncher:

```
    package ClientLauncher;

import Registratsiya.LoginAndPass;
import Tetris.GameTetris;


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;


public class AllGames extends JFrame {
            private JFrame parent;
            private JButton tetris;
    public void allGames(LoginAndPass account){
        parent = new JFrame("Настройки");
        Font font = new Font("asas",Font.LAYOUT_NO_LIMIT_CONTEXT,30);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Игры:");
        label.setFont(font);
        label.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        Dimension d = new Dimension(200,100);
        tetris = new JButton("Тетрис");
        tetris.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        tetris.setMinimumSize(d);
        tetris.setPreferredSize(d);
        tetris.setMaximumSize(d);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(tetris);

        parent.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel);
        parent.setLocation(500,100);
        parent.setSize(500,720);
        parent.setVisible(true);

        parent.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        tetris.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                parent.setVisible(false);
                   GameTetris gameTetris = new GameTetris();
                   gameTetris.go();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Когда нажимаю на кнопку должна запускаться игра, но она выглядит как на фото (а секунд через 40-50 наконец-то запускается, но я уже проиграл). Хотя если запускать её отдельно, то всё работает.

Comment: Проблема может быть в классе ClientLauncher.

Comment: И в чём она может заключатсья?

Comment: Щас, подожди, протру свой хрустальный шар, загляну в него, узнаю, что написано в том классе и что-нибудь обязательно посоветую. Но скорее всего проблема с импортом пакетов.

Comment: Вот тебе код: package ClientLauncher;

import Registratsiya.LoginAndPass;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

Comment: Приведите код и все подробности в самом вопросе с помощью кнопки "править"

Comment: Хрустального шара не имею, но я разложил карты и там вышло, что запускается тяжелая операция в гуи потоке!!!!

Comment: Я бы начал с изучения того, как запускается `GameTetris` отдельно. Наверное, есть какой-то `public static void main(...)`, в котором что-то происходит. Думаю, стоит сравнить то, что указано в `main` и то, что в методе `actionPerformed` обработчика кнопки для запуска тетриса в классе  `AllGames`.

Comment: @Maxim И что это может значит и как это исправить?

Comment: @gooamoko Я всё просмотрел вроде работает нормально

Comment: @WolFRam отличий в логике вызова тетриса нет? Если есть - то стоит внимательнее к ним присмотреться. Возможно, там и кроется разгадка.

Comment: @gooamoko Я просто создал новый поток при нажатии на кнопку и всё стало на свои места